# Localizing JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG "Save in:" label

Tags: java, swing, localization, jfilechooser

There is one item left which I don't know how to modify and that is the *`Save in:`* label when the `dialogType` is set to `JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG`.

As the label for *`Look in:`* shares the same place on the screen, I modified the `lookInLabelText` with `UIManager.put("FileChooser.lookInLabelText", "...")`, but to no avail.

Then I looked into the sources of `JFileChooser.java`, but there is not a single `JLabel` defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.saveInLabelText", "");
```

---

You must use either of:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showSaveDialog(parent);
```

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
chooser.showDialog(parent, null);
```

You must **not** use:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
chooser.showDialog(parent, "");
```

otherwise it becomes a `CUSTOM_DIALOG`, and `FileChooser.lookInLabelText` applies and `dialogTitle` must be set.

Comment: Thank you Francesco. I had tried "FileChooser.saveInLabelText", but forgot the get the file updated where the UIManager is set. Shame on me.